# What are SetupAPI,SetupAPI1,and SetupAPI2? And what the difference between them?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, mfc

Recently，I need to realize a little function in MFC by C++ which is used to get a list of available serial ports. And then I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1388871/how-do-i-get-a-list-of-available-serial-ports-in-win32). I need to know what is SetupAPI1 and SetupAPI2? Where can I get the `setup.dll` when I wanna use this way to realize my function?. During searching the Internet I found there is a [SetupAPI](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff550855(v=vs.85).aspx) but it seems another one.  Now, I am really confusing by these SetupAPI, SetupAPI1, and SetupAPI2. What are the differences? Where are they come from? And, how can I get them if I wanna to use these?

Comment: The [SO link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1388871/) you mention points to [EnumSerialPorts v1.27](http://www.naughter.com/enumser.html), written by PJ Naughter.  The functions SetupAPI1() and SetupAPI2() in EnumSerialPorts both use the Windows Device Manager "SetupDi" APIs.  This is precisely the [SetupAPI](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff550855%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) you asked about in your post.  'Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks a lot!! That's help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no such think as SetupAPI1 and SetupAPI2. There is a library named SetupAPI.

This answer you link to refers to a library named [EnumSerialPort](http://www.naughter.com/enumser.html). From that page:

> Internally the code provides 9 different ways (yes you read that right: Nine) of enumerating serial ports: Using CreateFile, QueryDosDevice, GetDefaultCommConfig, two ways using the Setup API, EnumPorts, WMI, Com Database & enumerating the values under the registry key HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\HARDWARE\DEVICEMAP\SERIALCOMM.
>
> ...
>
> All of the configuration of the code is controlled by the following preprocessor values: CENUMERATESERIAL_USE_STL, _AFX, NO_ENUMSERIAL_USING_CREATEFILE, NO_ENUMSERIAL_USING_QUERYDOSDEVICE, NO_ENUMSERIAL_USING_GETDEFAULTCOMMCONFIG, NO_ENUMSERIAL_USING_SETUPAPI1, NO_ENUMSERIAL_USING_SETUPAPI2, NO_ENUMSERIAL_USING_ENUMPORTS, NO_ENUMSERIAL_USING_WMI, NO_ENUMSERIAL_USING_COMDB & NO_ENUMSERIAL_USING_REGISTRY.

This library presents two different methods that rely on SetupAPI, and simply numbers them one and two. You can see these details and more by following the links.

Comment: Oh, really thanks! Till I saw the answer I finally realized the 9 ways all from EnumSerialPort. Except refer EnumSerialPort also have other ways like CreateFile,registry key...can list the serial ports. So, when I saw the 9 ways I didn't realize they all refer to EnumSerialPort . How stupid I am.