# Dynamically create multiple object instances of same class in c#

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, serial-port

I am building a device controller in C# that controls the flow rate of pumps. There is Form1 and a Pump-Class, holding all properties and methods of the pump that are accessible through the Form.  So far, everything works fine. However, there might be the case where there is more than one pump. Of course, I could run individual instances of the executable, but you know..

How can I create multiple instances of the pump-class according to my current demand. Maybe an extra Form upfront with an Add-Button, where it is possible to create as much pumps as needed?

Sure, this is comes down to a very basic question, but I am no professional programmer.. Any comments are highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

mulm

```
namespace PumpController
{

    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

        static Pump pump;

        public Form1()
        {

            InitializeComponent();

            cb_availablePorts.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList;
            cb_baudRates.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList;

            string[] availablePorts = SerialPort.GetPortNames();
            foreach (string item in availablePorts)
                {
                    cb_availablePorts.Items.Add(item);
                }

            string[] commonBaudRates = new string[] { "4800", "9600", "19200", "38400", "57600", "115200" };
            foreach (string item in commonBaudRates)
            {
                cb_baudRates.Items.Add(item);
            }
        }

        private void bt_valueUp_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!(pump == null))
            {
                pump.increaseValue();
            }           
        }

        private void bt_valueDown_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!(pump == null))
            {
                pump.decreaseValue();
            }
        }

        private void Form_Closing(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Hide();
            if (!(pump == null))
            {
                pump.Close();
            }                
        }

        private void bt_connect_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!(cb_availablePorts.SelectedItem == null) && !(cb_baudRates.SelectedItem == null))
            {
                Pump pump = new Pump(Convert.ToString(cb_availablePorts.SelectedItem), Convert.ToInt32(cb_baudRates.SelectedItem));
            }           
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `static Pump pump;` - This means only one instance of `Pump` will be available throughout the application. You can have multiple `Pump`s by creating an object of `Pump` as required(maybe on an Add Pump button click)

Comment: You may use a `List<Pump>` and on each add click add a new item to this list.

Comment: @kashi_rock I thought about creating a list, but wasnt sure if it might be better creating "individual" instances.

Comment: @ViVi But this way I would need to give individual names to the objects, right...

Comment: @mulm : I thought you only have 1 instance at a time. If you have multiple instances then `List<Pump>` is the best option

Comment: Yes, the point is I want the application to be extensible by means of having as much pump-instances as needed at a specific time. Will implement the list. Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comments lead to part of the answer and are right as far as they go.  However, one important thing has perhaps been overlooked -- the part about finding an(other) COM port.

Each time you instantiate a `new Pump` object, and add it to the `List<Pump>` collection, these objects will contend for the same COM port unless you allocate another port.

There is a well-accepted answer for this at [enumerating COM ports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1388871/how-do-i-get-a-list-of-available-serial-ports-in-win32).  Hate to provide a link as the heart of my answer, but if you have a four-object list of `Pump` objects contending for a single serial port, you could have troubles.

Comment: Of course this is an important point. In my experience dealing with COM ports can be really tricky. Howerver, I shortened the code a little. The final project will have some logic to check for this kind of conflicts.