# Is there a way to find all the COM port devices using windows 10 APIs

Tags: c#, windows-10, com-port

It is possible to get the details about the device on the COMP port if we know the COM port number.

```cs
var query = SerialDevice.GetDeviceSelector("COM3");
var deviceInformationCollection = await DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync(query);
```

However I am wondering if it possible to get the details about all the COM ports. I tried following but it does not work.

```cs
var query = SerialDevice.GetDeviceSelector("COM*");
var deviceInformationCollection = await DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync(query);
```

Comment: "Advanced Query Selector" - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/search/-search-3x-advancedquerysyntax , https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/devices-sensors/build-a-device-selector#aqs-string-examples

Comment: I tried this but it did not work. `query = @"System.Devices.InterfaceClassGuid:=""{86E0D1E0-8089-11D0-9CE4-08003E301F73}"" AND System.Devices.InterfaceEnabled:=System.StructuredQueryType.Boolean#True AND System.DeviceInterface.Serial.PortName:~~""COM""";`

Comment: What happens when only using the InterfaceClassGuid (or likewise, the other properties)?

Comment: Nothing, well when I call `GetDeviceSelector` I get `System.Devices.InterfaceClassGuid:="{86E0D1E0-8089-11D0-9CE4-08003E301F73}" AND System.Devices.InterfaceEnabled:=System.StructuredQueryType.Boolean#True AND System.DeviceInterface.Serial.PortName:="COM13" OR (System.Devices.InterfaceClassGuid:="{86E0D1E0-8089-11D0-9CE4-08003E301F73}" AND System.Devices.InterfaceEnabled:=System.StructuredQueryType.Boolean#True AND (System.Devices.DeviceInstanceId := FTDIBUS\VID_0403+PID_6001+FTY435VMA\0000))`. If I try with the first part of the expression (before OR) it also does not work.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1394301/263693