# C++ QueryDosDeviceA() return 0 but COMX is connected

Tags: c++, winapi, serial-port

so I'm doing a function to retrieve all the COM serial port names connected to the system using `QueryDosDeviceA`

I tried to use `CreatFileA` with `"\\\\.\\COM6"`, and it doesn't throw me any errors.
But `QueryDosDeviceA` with `"COM6"` or `"\\\\.\\COM6"`

*Function.cpp*

```cpp
std::vector<std::string> SerialPort::_SerialList()
{
    std::vector<std::string> serialList;
    std::string COMName("\\\\.\\COM"), queryName(COMName); //also tried with COMName("COM")
    CHAR bufferTragetPath[5000];
    std::string tmp;
    DWORD path_size(0);

    //test each COM name to get the one used by the system
    for (int i(0); i < 255; i++)
    {
        queryName = COMName + std::to_string(i);
        //Query the path of the COMName
        path_size = QueryDosDeviceA((LPCSTR)&queryName, (LPSTR)&bufferTragetPath, 5000);

        std::cout << std::endl << "Path for " << queryName << ":" << path_size;

        if (path_size != 0) {
            std::cout << "pushing..." << queryName << " on " << bufferTragetPath << std::endl;
            serialList.push_back(queryName);
        }
    }
    return serialList;
}
```

And here is the output :

```cpp
Path for \\.\COM0:0
Path for \\.\COM1:0
Path for \\.\COM2:0
Path for \\.\COM3:0
Path for \\.\COM4:0
Path for \\.\COM5:0
Path for \\.\COM6:0
Path for \\.\COM7:0
Path for \\.\COM8:0
Path for \\.\COM9:0
...
Path for \\.\COM253:0
Path for \\.\COM254:0Port name: \\.\COM6
Hello World !
```

So it's finding nothing but the COM6 port can be used by CreateFileA

Comment: `(LPCSTR)&queryName` is an incorrect way to convert from std::string to LPCSTR

Comment: What type of device is it? I tried your code - changing to "COMx" instead of UNC as well as `(LPCSTR)&queryName` to `queryName.c_str()` - and it found 2 com0com devices and one FTDI device on my system.

Comment: See also: [How do I get a list of available serial ports in Win32?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1388871)

Comment: for retrieve all the COM serial port names need use `CM_Get_Device_Interface_ListW` with `GUID_DEVINTERFACE_COMPORT`

Comment: @JohnnyMopp I have to use QueryDosDevice bcp it's one of the constraint that I have for the project

Comment: @dresscherjm I changed the method of converting, and it worked ! Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @user253751, @JohnnyMopp, @dresscherjm
And @RemyLebeau

Here is the code that include the solution:

```cpp
std::vector<std::string> SerialPort::_SerialList()
{
    std::vector<std::string> serialList;
    std::string COMName("COM"), queryName("");
    CHAR bufferTragetPath[5000];
    std::string tmp;
    DWORD path_size(0);

    //test each COM name to get the one used by the system and get his description name
    for (int i(0); i < 255; i++)
    {
        queryName = COMName + std::to_string(i);

        //Query the path of the COMName
        path_size = QueryDosDeviceA(queryName.c_str(), bufferTragetPath, 5000);
        std::cout << std::endl << "Path for " << queryName << ":" << path_size << "   " << queryName;
        if (path_size != 0) {
            std::cout << "pushing..." << queryName << " on " << bufferTragetPath << std::endl;
            serialList.push_back(tmp);
        }
    }
    return serialList;
}
```

Basically i change the convertion of queryName from string to LPCSTR

```
//LPCSTR => Long Pointer Const String(= const char)
queryName.c_str() //return queryName as const char*
```

I've also removed a cast from `bufferTragetPath` that was useless

```
//from 
(LPSTR)&bufferTragetPath
//to
bufferTragetPath //cause bufferTragetPath is char *
```

Comment: You have a memory leak. You are `new[]`'ing memory and assigning that to `queryName`, and then later you are re-assigning `queryName` to point at different memory, leaking the `new[]`'ed memory.  And even if you didn't re-assign `queryName`, you are missing a `delete[] queryName;` statement. You shouldn't be using `new[]` at all in this code, it is not needed: `std::string queryName; ... queryName = COMName + std::to_string(i); QueryDosDeviceA(queryName.c_str(), bufferTragetPath, 5000);` (note I also removed the `LPCSTR` cast from `bufferTragetPath`, too).

Comment: @RemyLebeau Yes, thanks ! I fixed that I forgot the memory leak existence -_-'  
And yes you're right I did some useless cast I fixed that too.

Comment: I am glad you have got your solution and thanks for your sharing, I would appreciate it if you mark them as answer and this will be beneficial to other community.