# Define the COM port for other computers

Tags: windows, bash, serial-port

I got a Silicon Labs CP2102 USB to UART Bridge and i need it to transfer data from my GUI to a Nucleos F446RE.
I want to know if there is a way to define the COM port for the Bridge for other computers as well since on my computer it is COM8 and for a diffrent computer it is COM7.
I know that i could change it manually but not anyone got admin rights and if there is any way to do it automatically it would be great.

Comment: What language? What OS? [How do I get a list of available serial ports in Win32?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1394301) You probably don't want to hard-code or re-assign port numbers. Make you software flexible enough to use any port.

Comment: I use c++ for the communication between GUI and Nucleos and want to use it for windows. In the future i want to get it working on linux as well.

Answer (score 1):

<strike>If you can, avoid a USB-to-UART bridge for exactly the reason you describe: it basically prevents a good user experience.</strike>

It is possible to change the COM port number after installation, just not to preselect it. During installation of the virtual COM device, Windows automatically chooses a COM port number that is **not already in use**. The avoiding conflicts part is important, and reveals why it is impossible to have the hardware choose the number. (Thanks to Ben Voigt for this part.)

You have several options:

- The Nucleo F446RE board has a UBS interface. So you can directly connect it to your PC without a USB-to-UART bridge. Of course, the firmware needs to implement a USB device, preferably with a custom protocol and with WinUSB descriptors. That way, no device driver installation is needed and your application can communicate with the board using the WinUSB APIs.
- If this is not possible, another alternative is to select the COM port with matching attributes, in particular with the matching vendor and product ID (VID and PID) - see links below. That way, you can at least narrow it down to a device with a Silicon Labs CP2102, which will often be sufficient to uniquely identify the port.
- Another option is to use a USB-to-UART bridge that allows to configure a string descriptor. That way, you can uniquely identify the COM port. For a true plug and play experience, you would need to select a bridge chip that either does not need driver installation as it implements the standardized USB CDC ACM protocol (e.g. PL2303GD) or can automatically install the drivers (such as the FTDI chips).

Links:

- https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/349002/Select-a-USB-Serial-Device-via-its-VID-PID
- https://aticleworld.com/get-com-port-of-usb-serial-device/

Comment: Your first paragraph has nothing to do with the rest of your answer.  A separate bridge chip can enumerate as a Virtual COM Port or as another device class (e.g. FTDI's D2XX mode).  A separate bridge chip can have a known VID/PID or special string descriptors allowing you to identify it.  Yes, those are better ways that relying on a consistent COM port number, but that is completely independent of whether the USB function is integrated in the MCU or a separate chip.

Comment: I agree that it would be possible to create USB bridge chips that provide a plug an play experience. But I'm not aware that any such chip exists. FTDI chips with D2XX mode require driver installation on Windows, so it's not plug and play.

Comment: The only exception would be a USB-to-UART bridge chip with configurable string descriptors and drivers that are already included in Windows. Do such chips exist?

Comment: On Windows, any USB device requires driver installation.  The only difference is between an inbox driver (co-signed by Microsoft and preloaded on the computer), one available through Windows Update (co-signed by Microsoft but not preloaded), or a third-party driver.  FTDI drivers install automatically unless you've used a custom VID/PID.

Comment: I'm not recommending it (I hate products based on the prolific chips) but "The PL2303GD  implements  the  standard  USB  CDC  Device  which  is  natively  supported  in  most  of  operating systems; so the PL2303GD does not need any custom driver installation..... The  OTPROM  allows  vendors  to  customize  some  USB descriptors and configurations like USB Vendor ID (VID), Product ID (PID), Manufacturer and Product strings, USB Serial Number, power configuration and GPIO & other IO configurations. "

Comment: That's cool: So an FTDI chip with a modified string descriptor would work. It requires driver installation but the drivers are bundled. It's also cool that there are finally bridge chips implementing USB CDC. In addition to PL2303GD, I'm also aware of such a chip from WCH. That way, plug and play experience is even better.

Comment: However, other than what you are saying, there are many USB devices that do NOT need driver installation: all devices implementing a standardized USB protocol such as keyboard, mouse, audio, web cam, network adapter, CDC ACM (used by PL2303GD) as well as devices implementing a custom protocol with WinUSB descriptors.

Comment: Those definitely do need driver installation, it's just a first-party driver (written by the OS vendor, not merely co-signed).  Many organizations choose to block said driver installation for security.

Comment: You are correct that it will not work in many bigger companies as they restrict what can be connected via the USB port. In such a context, all the above solutions will probably fail. I don't fully understand the details of what Windows does when a USB device is connected for the first time. Does it always install a new driver instance, even for keyboards and mice?

Comment: Yes, when a new device is detected it always attempts driver installation (if no matching driver is found then it won't install a new driver instance).  If the driver is already being used for other devices on the system, it might be better to say it installs the driver into a new device instance, because the driver itself isn't really instanced the same way devices are.  But it's running the same "driver installation procedure", complete with running co-installers.

Comment: FWIW, It *is* possible to change the COM port number after installation, just not to preselect it.  During installation of the virtual COM device, Windows automatically choose a COM port number **that is not already in use**.  The avoiding conflicts part is important, and reveals why it is impossible to have the hardware choose the number.