# Can't access COM port greater than 99 in C#

Tags: c#, serial-port

I have a small issue with a program I am writing in Visual Studio 2022.

I have numerous devices that attach to the USB virtual com port, and because of the way that Windows enumerates the USB to serial chip in the device, I can have com ports listed as well over 100 (576 at last count).  These com ports are not connected simultaneously, but one at a time, each enumerating as one higher than the previous port.

My problem is that I can access up to COM99, but when it rolls over to 100, the port will not connect.  There is no error message or exception thrown.

The ComboBox will find port 100 (or greater) but the serial port will not connect.  I am wondering if the System.IO.Ports Serial function is truncating my port string to "10" for instance.

I should mention that this code works flawlessly up to port 99 (on many different computers). I can see port 100 or greater in the ComboBox, but no success.  This should be a simple thing but I'm baffled.

Any help or suggestions gratefully received.

I am using this code for com port connections:

```
private bool ScanSerial()
    {
        bool success = false;
        
        //Open the serial port and get the number of the active serial port
        serialPortComboBox.Items.Clear();
        string[] serialPortNumbers = SerialPort.GetPortNames();

        

        // Iterate each port and add it to the serial port drop down box
        foreach (string port in serialPortNumbers)
        {
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(port))
            {
                serialPortComboBox.Items.Add(port);
                success = true;
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("No available serial ports", "Serial Ports", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
                
                
                serialPortInUse = null;
                return false;
            }
        }

        // default the highest numbered port as the port to use - the program will try to connect to this port
        // if it doesn't find a device, user will have to override the method by selecting from the dropdown and trying again
        string lastPort = serialPortNumbers.Max();
        serialPortComboBox.Text = lastPort;
        label10.Text = lastPort;
        serialPortInUse = lastPort;
        return success;
    }
```

```
public bool Connect(string comPort)
        {
            bool success;

            // Baud rate 57600, 8, N, 1 is standard
            {

                // Allow the user to set the appropriate properties.
                _serialPort.PortName = comPort;
                _serialPort.BaudRate = 57600;
                _serialPort.Parity = Parity.None;
                _serialPort.DataBits = 8;
                _serialPort.StopBits = StopBits.One;
                _serialPort.Handshake = Handshake.None;
                _serialPort.Encoding = Encoding.GetEncoding(0);
                _serialPort.ReadTimeout = 500;
                _serialPort.WriteTimeout = 500;
            }

            try
            {
                _serialPort.Open();
                success = true;
                _continue = true;
            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("An exception was thrown: \n {0}", ex.ToString());
                Console.WriteLine("Press enter to continue.");
                Console.ReadLine();
                success = false;
            }
            return success;
        }
```

Comment: what does the comPort string contain? Is it correct?

Comment: It contains the value 100 or higher and seems to be correct.  I have checked it with HyperTerminal and the port values definitely match.  It just seems that my code won't open the port.

Comment: The source code presented in your question article does not show what the actual parameter string to pass to the connect function is. Isn't it passing the interactive input on WPF or Form as it is? Please review the input data. Please refer to this article. [Win32 Device Namespaces](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/naming-a-file#win32-device-namespaces), [Unity Connect Serial Port. Help me please.](https://answers.unity.com/questions/1362201/unity-connect-serial-port-help-me-please.html)

Comment: @kunif  Thank you for the pointer.  I will check that out

Answer (score 0):

You can find GetPortNames() source code on github, it iterates over a registry key

https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/b056b7b6a1eca5171e42f697a0b3d3c60d1fc048/src/libraries/System.IO.Ports/src/System/IO/Ports/SerialPort.Win32.cs

There several methods to get the ports. Checkout this post.
[How do I get a list of available serial ports in Win32?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1388871/how-do-i-get-a-list-of-available-serial-ports-in-win32)

Since I guess you are using some kind of vendor specific serialport virtual adapter it make sense to search the registry for a high port e.g COM255 to find a more reliable registry way. I would guess it is an USB PNP device.
Maybe somewhere in HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Enum

Comment: I will give that a try, thanks.  My code does actually find the right COM port (verified with HyperTerminal), but the port won't open.

Comment: Yeah i looked into the source of _serialPort.PortName = comPort; there isn't some truncating at the string length, the only difference i could find is how this end up in the current os. Cause new .net variants are multiplatform. Try to run your code in net6 and or net452. Check out https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/sys/system/io/ports/SerialPort.cs,ae0a3218c6c9f7fe

Comment: I'll take a peek at the link, and also try to run with .NET 6.  Thanks for the info