# Loop on serial ports

Tags: c#, port

I'm using c# FW 4.0.
I want to iterate on all the serial ports in my computer and get the full name of each one of them.
For example, I would like to see "Prolific USB-to-Serial Comm Port(COM6)" and not just COM6.

[image]

This is my current code which gives me only the COM/1/6 etc...

```
           string[] ports = SerialPort.GetPortNames();


        foreach (string port1 in ports)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(port1);

        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could make use of WMI, take a look at the [WMI Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394572%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Answer by Juanma, [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1081871/how-to-find-available-com-ports).

```
try
{
    ManagementObjectSearcher searcher =
        new ManagementObjectSearcher("root\\WMI",
        "SELECT * FROM MSSerial_PortName");

    foreach (ManagementObject queryObj in searcher.Get())
    {
        Console.WriteLine("-----------------------------------");
        Console.WriteLine("MSSerial_PortName instance");
        Console.WriteLine("-----------------------------------");
        Console.WriteLine("InstanceName: {0}", queryObj["InstanceName"]);

        Console.WriteLine("-----------------------------------");
        Console.WriteLine("MSSerial_PortName instance");
        Console.WriteLine("-----------------------------------");
        Console.WriteLine("PortName: {0}", queryObj["PortName"]);

        //If the serial port's instance name contains USB 
        //it must be a USB to serial device
        if (queryObj["InstanceName"].ToString().Contains("USB"))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(queryObj["PortName"] + " 
            is a USB to SERIAL adapter/converter");
        }
    }
}
catch (ManagementException e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("An error occurred while querying for WMI data: " + e.Message);
}
```